# Unknown Commands Give "Bus error (core dumped)"

Tags: command-line, apt

Any unknown command in Terminal outputs "Bus error (core dumped)." For example typing the command "foobar" gives "Bus error (core dumped)" and typing the command "asldkfjs" gives the same thing. Anyone know how to fix this?

I've tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade and restarted my computer and nothing works.

Some more information that might be helpful. If I press ctrl-alt-f1 to get in the TTY terminal and log in it gives the following errors:

[297.006180] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev nvme0n1, sector 12452408

(and more with different numbers)

Comment: Probably a problem with the `command-not-found` and `command-not-found-data` packages. Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall command-not-found command-not-found-data`.

Comment: That didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Reboot to single user mode, `fsck /dev/nme0n1` - physical I/O failed to that disk location - either your disk is breaking or your disk structure is confused,